# Can't install nano via homebrew on m1 Mac

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1, nano

My main goal was to have syntax highlighting for nano.
Apparently my nano seems to be pico 5.09 instead of nano.
Running **which nano**, returns:

```
/usr/bin/nano
```

Then I tried to install the real nano with brew, there I get this error:

```
Warning: Treating nano as a formula. For the cask, use homebrew/cask/nano
Error: nano dependencies not built for the arm64 CPU architecture:
  gettext was built for x86_64
```

I think brew looks like the legit arm version.

```
which brew
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
```

What could I do to have the end result of
Nano with syntax highlighting?

Comment: `nano` is symlinked to `pico`.

Comment: See https://osxdaily.com/2022/03/27/get-nano-text-editor-mac/

Answer (score 0):

If your brew dependencies are out of date, this could happen.

```
% brew update && brew upgrade && brew install nano
Already up-to-date.
...
% brew install nano
Warning: Treating nano as a formula. For the cask, use homebrew/cask/nano
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/nano/manifests/6.4
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/nano/blobs/sha256:7206f1c20ac7f
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sh
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring nano--6.4.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> nano cask is installed, skipping link.
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/nano/6.4: 103 files, 3.2MB
==> Running `brew cleanup nano`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
```